# Nested foreach loops with side effects for Entity Framework

Tags: c#

I have problem with nested foreach loops because of following example:

```
var someList = new List<SimpleC>();

simpleA = database.SimpleA.ToList();
simpleB = database.SimpleB.ToList();

foreach (var a in simpleA)
{
    foreach (var b in simpleB)
    {
        var c = new simpleC();
        c.simpleAId = a.Id;
        c.simpleAName = a.Name;
        c.simpleBName = b.Name;

        someList.Add(c);
    }
}

return someList;
```

The problem: imagine first iteration it goes to first foreach loop then to second foreach loop it initiates new object, maps values and adds newly initiated object to new list, but when second iteration comes instead of going back to first foreach loop it continues with second foreach loop and it loops through second until it finishes, I understand that's how C# works, but I need side effect for it to continue to first foreach loop to get new values.

Comment: `simpleC.Id = a.Id;` should probably be `c.Id = a.Id;` and so on... Other than that, if not mistaken I don't see any other issue, nor does your issue make sense to me, can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, could you be a little more clear?

Comment: C# iterates through second loop until it finishes, but I need it to go back to first loop for new values because when he continues second loop simpleA values don't change. Doesn't it make sense if loops are nested that it should go through each loop for each iteration instead of be stuck in which ever loop is last.

Comment: @ceasar.ramone so you are only wanting to take the first in that list then or? It doesn't make sense, what condition would be present to select an item from that list then if you only want it one time?

Comment: That list will be returned as json, but for each iteration simpleA values don't change because he is stuck on second loop and only simpleB values change

Comment: @ceasar.ramone are you sure simpleA has more than one item?

Comment: Both have equal amount of items, both have 15 items as count in debugging

Comment: just give us an example of simpleA, simpleB and the expected simpleC

Comment: Is there some kind of relation to these list? If not, use a `for(int i` syntax and pull out your object from `simpleB` based on that index, don't loop. For example `for (int i = 0; i <= simpleA.Count; i++)
{
    var c = new simpleC();
        c.simpleAId = simpleA[i].Id;
        c.simpleAName = simpleA[i].Name;
        c.simpleBName = simpleB[i].Name;

        someList.Add(c);
}`

Comment: Can you show an example of an input, current output, and expected output?

Comment: I've tried to use normal for loop but the issue is when object is deleted in database it cannot go by index anymore because if we have 15 items and delete 14 item now it will loop through first 13 items and stop there because 14 doesn't exist as Id in database table

Comment: @ceasar.ramone these details are important for us to help you, so far, twice now, you've changed what is expected. Until you can update your post to include, expected behavior and output, we are not much of help.

Comment: Input:
All three are list of objects and simpleA object has Id and Name, simpleB has Name
simpleC empty but simpleC needs both simpleA and simpleB in one object and it needs to loop through every item in simpleA and simpleB and add new object to simpleC as simpleA and simpleB objects together

Comment: simpleC is supposed to be combination as one object of simpleA and simpleB and those objects outputs are list

Comment: I probably complicated it more than it should be, but it's hard to explain when I cannot give you whole code and the look of table, but imagine each object contains Id and Name and we only need simpleA id, simpleA name and simpleB name to form new object that will go to simpleC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be much better served by not trying to iterate this manually, establishing a relationship and querying it as a join set of entities:

```
var results = database.SimpleA 
   .Join(database.SimpleB, 
      a => a.ID,       
      b => b.Post_ID,   /
      (a, b) => new { colA = a, colB = b }) 
   .Select new SimpleA(){
      Property1 = a.Col1,
      Property2 = b.Col3,
      Property4 = a.Col2
   }).ToList();
```

This is only mostly functional as a starting point. You might need a left outer join instead.

Another option, if A and B have a fk constraint in the database, then you may use Navigation properties instead of a join.

If for whatever reason, your loop is required we can try and breakdown the issue:

```
foreach (var a in simpleA)
{
    foreach (var b in simpleB)  // There is no relationship here!
    {
        var c = new simpleC();
        c.simpleAId = a.Id;
        c.simpleAName = a.Name;
        c.simpleBName = b.Name;

        someList.Add(c);
    }
}
```

You could try using the index, but that is very likely to cause issues.

Instead:

```
foreach (var a in simpleA)
{
    var matchedB = simpleB.Where(x => x.Id == a.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    var c = new simpleC();
    c.simpleAId = a.Id;
    c.simpleAName = a.Name;
    c.simpleBName = matchedB.Name;

    someList.Add(c);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I'm understanding your question, is that you don't want it to loop through in a nested fashion, but only loop once. To do that you'd do it like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < simpleA.Count; i++)
{
    var c = new simpleC();
        c.simpleAId = simpleA[i].Name;
        c.simpleAName = simpleA[i].Name;
        c.simpleBName = simpleB[i].Name;
    someList.Add(c);
}
```

Comment: Read the comments before posting solution please.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I started typing long before I read those comments. Posting a solution, based on the information presented at the time of writing.

Comment: The issue with that solution is when one object is deleted it cannot find more than last deleted object, if we have 5 objects and 3 object is deleted now loop will loop through 2 objects

Comment: @ceasar.ramone, deleted from where? Simply change the `simpleA.Count` to `yourArrayThatGetsDeletedElements.Count`